# WPF: Binding to property of a class in a ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding

i have a class called `Robot`:

```
public class Robot
{
    public string name { get; private set; }

    public Robot(string robotName)
    {
        name = robotName;
    }
}
```

I made in my ModelView an ObservableCollection of this class:

```
public ObservableCollection<Robot> Robots { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Robot>();
```

And I need now to bind this ObservableCollection to my ListView, but I need the property `name` binded to the ListView, not the class converted to a string.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Robots}" />
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This question surely has many answers here. Search for `DataTemplate`.
If you don't find anything, follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to the name of the item property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Robots}" DisplayMemberPath="name" />
```

---

The Robot property should be named `Name` - using Pascal Casing to adhere to widely accepted naming conventions:

```
public class Robot
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Robot(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The XAML would then be

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Robots}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a way better solution! The property I used is `DisplayMemberPath` because `DisplayMemberName` does not exist, but it works anyway.
I am still learning and just started in August my 3 year-education for being a software developer - my educator already told me paying more attention to the naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did of course mean DisplayMemberPath.